# Can you use the Vimeo API to return videos uploaded by region or liked by region?

Tags: api, geolocation, location, vimeo, vimeo-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the Vimeo API to return videos based on where in the world the video was upload from or alternatively where in the world the video has been liked from? Does Vimeo store any location specific information? Any help on this would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. Vimeo currently doesn't expose any geolocation data via their api. Can't say whether or not they're tracking it internally on their backend.

They did just launch a new help page:

https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Might be worth messaging through that site to confirm.